# Angular CLI and external modules

Tags: angular-cli

We have the following situation:

- application A provides a CDN JS bundle containing Angular objects to be used by a consuming application
- application A provides an npm package called with only d.ts files an an index.d.ts file
- application B adds a script tag towards the CDN bundle
- application B consumes the npm package in an Angular CLI context

--> So somewhere in a file an "import MyComponent from 'xxx'" is done which works fine (the d.ts files are detected and providing typing)

- when the Angular cli ng build command is called it says that module 'xxx' cannot be found

How can I make this work with Angular CLI?

In Webpack I would be able to use the externals property and this would work fine.

Actually I think it should be the same behavior as @types packages...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See article (not supported at the moment):
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8607